# Using call to pass context

Tags: javascript, call

I'm trying to use `call` to pass the context of the Utilities object so I can access its members (allData array, etc) within the `myTest` function.

I'm getting error:

> ReferenceError: allData is not defined

This tells me the context is lost and I guess I'm not binding the context correctly. How do I do this?

```
var Utilities = {
    allData : [],
    storage : [],

    apiRequest : function () {
        this.allData = ["a","b","c"];
        var myTest = this.allData.map.call(this, function (i, el) {
            var url = 'testPHP.php/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=zh-CN&q=' + i;
            return $.get(url, function (returned_data) {
                this.storage.push(returned_data);
            });
        });

        $.when.apply($, myTest).done(function () {
            log('done!');
            log(this.storage[i]);
        });
```

Comment: The error message you see has nothing to do with context. You're simply referencing a variable that doesn't exist. `allData` isn't a variable - it's a property of `Utilities`. So use `Utilities.allData` or possibly `this.allData`. Depending on how you call the `apiRequest` method, `this` may not be correct to use.

Comment: @Ian okay. If I wanted to reference the properties of Utilities within another function where the context is lost, how would I do that? I thought `call` binds the context

Comment: Let me ask you this - is this your actual code, or an example? First thing is that a lot of this isn't necessary (can be done in a different way) to overcome problems with `this`. Second thing - your most recent edit - `this.storage` is in a nested function, where the value of `this` is now not the same as the `.map.call()`'s

Comment: You're right that `call` binds the context, but you're confusing what's being bound. In your code, for example, your code `this.allData.map.call(this ...` is  saying "take `this` (`Utilities`) and call `.map()` on it". That doesn't make sense. `this.allData.map` is a generic reference to the `Array.prototype.map` function, and by using `.call()`, you're telling it what to loop over - `this`. `call()` isn't as useful for built-in functions, but more helpful for calling created functions with different contexts...and often can be replaced with by using parameters

Comment: Hopefully this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/621me9uu/

Comment: @Ian very helpful, thank you. I get confused with context in js

Comment: @Growler— *this* isn't "context". It's one property of an execution context that is set by how a function is called or through the use of *bind*. You can't pass an execution context, or even reference it. You can assign and bind to the object assigned to *this* though.

Comment: @RobG: Uh oh, I always deliberately name it "*`this` context*"? Most people confuse `this` with the scope, and I think "context object [for the call]" is an appropriate term to clear up the concept. I don't think anyone who knows about the language spec term "execution context" has problems with the `this` keyword :-)

Comment: @Bergi—I feel that calling *this* "context" infers that its value is related to where a function is called from (i.e. the context of the call), when it is completely independent of that. It's a parameter, so why not just call it that?

Comment: @RobG: Yeah, I mean a context *for* the call not a context of the call - the object *on* which the function is called. Of course, we can technically call it the *thisArg* parameter, but I don't think anyone who hasn't read the spec understands that, or can infer a purpose from that term.

Answer (score 2):

## Reminder

There is only function level context in Javascript, and `this` is nothing more than a local variable. By default, `this` is set to the global `window` object:

```
function me () { return this; };
me() === window; // true
```

Or to the object from which the function was invoked:

```
var o = {};
o.me = me;
o.me() === o; // true
```

Knowing this, read the following carefully:

```
var me = o.me;
me === o.me; // true, not a copy
me() === o; // false
me() === window; // true

var p = {};
p.me = o.me;
p.me() === p; // true
o.me() === o; // true
```

As you can see, `this` is automatically set at function invocation. This is the default behaviour, but you can also do it yourself using either `.call()` or `.apply()` (one shot):

```
me.call(o) === o; // true
me.apply(o) === o; // true
p.me.call(o) === o; // true
me() === window; // true
```

And more recently, `.bind()` (permanent):

```
me = me.bind(o);
me() === o; // true
me() === window; // false
```

---

## Your question

I would use `.bind()`:

```
var Utilities = {
    allData : [],
    storage : [],

    apiRequest : function () {
        this.allData = ["a","b","c"];
        var myTest = this.allData.map(function (i, el) {
            var url = 'testPHP.php/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=zh-CN&q=' + i;
            return $.get(url, function (returned_data) {
                this.storage.push(returned_data);
            }.bind(this));
        }.bind(this));

        $.when.apply($, myTest).done(function () {
            log('done!');
            // I've added a loop here
            var i, l = arguments.length;
            for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                log(this.storage[i]);
            }
        }.bind(this));
```

Comment: Actually `this` is more a local constant than a "variable" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Great answer above. One thing to emphasize at this point: whenever you bind the object at initialization it will be bound and **cannot** be call/apply'd using another context anymore. IMO it's up to you whether to use `call`/`apply` (**at runtime**) OR .bind (**permanently**).

Going from here:

> I'm trying to use call to pass the context of the Utilities object so I can access its members (allData array, etc) within the myTest function.

```
var OtherTest = function() {
    this.dataStorage.push(["ok"]);
    console.log(arguments);
}

var Utilities = {
    dataStorage: [],
    allData: [],
    apiRequest: function() {
        this.allData = ["a","b","c"];

        OtherTest.apply(this,arguments);

    }
}


Utilities.apiRequest('hu','hu');
console.log(Utilities.dataStorage[0]);
```

Since `this` is a reference to the object, it can be mutated at any time after initialization making it easy to use `call`/`apply` to pass the context **which is the `Utilities` Object** in this case.